# Why add a sunny-side up egg?

Tags: eggs, presentation

On Food Network, a lot of the shows add a sunny-side up egg to their dish, perhaps to make it more "elegant".

Some examples:  burgers, veal cutlets, corned beef hash

Is this about elegance, or is does adding an egg improve or otherwise enhance the dish?
(let's say versus no egg or an omelet type egg?)

Comment: This seems to be the epitome of "primarily opinion-based". What is "elegance" but a subjective assessment of one's own opinion of what makes something "elegant". If you want to know why a broadcast personality chooses to enhance "elegance" with a particular garnish or ingredient, you need to ask that person. The rest of us don't have any particular insight into their thinking that would be useful.

Comment: Since I can't contact expert chefs on Food Network, I thought I would ask here.

Comment: Plating or how the food appears on the dish, is of major importance on these shows.  I still don't know why Bobby Flay would add a sunny side egg on top of his dishes to make them elegant.  Is this a technique taught in culinary schools?

Comment: Be careful of descriptions from entertainment shows on television including the so-called "news". Television is always self-promoting and will describe things in an over-the-top manner in all things. Source: me. 10 years in television and radio.

Comment: Allow me to make an edit to your question will that will increase the likelihood of it remaining open.  If you disagree it can be rolled back.

Comment: I appreciate the edit but honestly this question is pretty much always going to be ultimately opinionated: people do it because they like it.

Comment: @Cascabel I have to disagree.  People do lots of things in the kitchen because "they like it."  It doesn't mean there is not an objective answer to the question.  Adding a fried egg, or an egg yolk to a dish might certainly be popular in restos and on food tv...but, as I point out in my answer, the saucing issue is an objective and practical reason to do it.  I realize you are only one the the close votes, but I think this is a valid question, and I think the concept of saucing is a valid answer.  I would appeal to you and the other close votes to re-open this question.

Comment: @moscafj Okay, but why is adding a sauce a good thing? Would "it adds a sauce?" be an answer to "why put gravy on things?" Saying it adds a sauce is just a description of what adding an egg means, not really a "why". And even if we do decide that's an answer, how do we allow that answer, without also allowing purely opinion-based answers like "because it makes it richer"? I'd suggest taking this to meta; there were other close votes too.

Comment: @Cascabel yeah...my experience on meta doesn't give me much optimism for change.  The question is why add an egg.  One answer is it provides a sauce.  It's not complicated.  It's not an opinion.  It's not the same question as why put a sauce on (or in your words, "why put gravy on things").  The question is why add an egg.  BTW, the other close votes were present before the editing of the question, which changed it from an opinion based question "why does the egg make the dish more elegant."  I think it is a good question.  I think I answer it.  I suspect there are other objective answers.

Comment: @moscafj  I don't think this is something I'm going to change my mind about based on a couple comments. If you ask on meta, I promise I will engage with an open mind (and speak mine as well); I'm not sure what else I can offer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "elegance", as that is a matter of opinion, but an egg with a runny yolk provides an instant sauce for the dish.  It can be delicious.

Comment: _"I don't know about "elegance""_ -- uh, okay...so, this isn't an answer after all? It seems this should have been posted as a comment, if at all.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @PeterDuniho, but the answer that I provided suggests that the yolk acts as a sauce, which is often why it is included.  Since, as you point out, "elegance" is a matter of opinion, I offer an objective reason why an egg might be added to a dish.  Therefore, it is indeed an answer...and one that actually might be helpful to the OP.